# GeoServer Roles and Job Description

Tags: geoserver, administration

Sorry if my question is a little bit weird.

I want to give all my team members a job title but I am not sure what to give the ones who are dealing with GeoServer and he is a web developer at the same time.

Also where can I find a description of GeoServer admin role?

Comment: Please let us know the Geoserver version that you are using..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated answer :

Please check [this](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/security/index.html) link . In which you will get all information regarding Geo-server admin role, Security,and security tutorial.(for version 2.2.x)

Comment: Thank. it is 2.2.3. but What do you call the guy who takes care of all Geoserver  matters in your team?

Comment: @Oxi its called "GIS Administrator" (Familiar with well-known  GIS software's + he knows installation/configuration and handling security issues). Due to manpower issue here I am handling this type of work..